# How to match a backspace character in a regular expression in Vim ex command?

Tags: regex, vim

Do I use a unicode character substitution?  I've seen posts saying use "\b" but that's a word boundary as far as I know.

I'm asking because I saw it in a Vimgolf problem:

```
Vjd:%s/.<BS>,/\r/g<CR>ddkkkkjddkkkkdd<Esc>:wq<CR>
```

Comment: I'm kind of confused. Why do you need to match a backspace character?

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz - edited the question above

Comment: `\b` is not  a word boundary for vim regex ! `\b matches <BS>`

Comment: Upvote for http://www.vimgolf.com/  :)

Comment: I guess you can use `^H` for representing backspace. Press Ctrl and v and then h macros o insert mode hat character.

Answer (score 1):

In most regex flavours, you can use `[\b]`. While `\b` normally matches a word boundary, in a character class it matches the backspace character (ASCII 8).

Answer (score 1):

There is always that universal unambiguous standby hex form `\x08`